# data table shift column

Tags: r, data.table

I often receive data with some fields contaminated by a "improper" separator, so when it's loaded it ends being like this:

```
library(data.table)
a <- data.table(x = c("AA", "AB", "A"), y = c(2, 4, "C"), z = c(NA, NA, 6))
```

when what I expect is

```
 b <- data.table(x = c("AA", "AB", "AC"), y = c(2, 4, 6))
```

Please notice that I often have many columns **after** the problematic one (in this example, I'd have columns AA, AB ... after `z`)

This is what I've tried, with the obvious result:

```
a[3, .SD[, 2] := .SD[, 3], .SDcols = c("y", "z")] 
# Error in `[.data.table`(a, 3, `:=`(.SD[, 2], .SD[, 3]), .SDcols = c("y",  : 
  LHS of := isn't column names ('character') or positions ('integer' or 'numeric')
```

If I already have `a`, what do I need to do to convert from `a` to `b`? I don't really need a lot of automation to find the culprit, as I can pinpoint those cases easily. Thanks

Comment: Probably worth fixing on ingestion (with `fread` or whatever).

Comment: @Frank, how would you achieve that? I think what happened is that the x field had "A,C" in the `x` when it was first generated by the software. But I'm given xlsx files read from that, so when I receive them they're already contaminated. My only chance is to fix them in Excel?

Comment: No, I mean when you use readXLS or whatever R function, you can probably tweak its options so as to not split on commas within a cell. Actually, I would expect the default to be not splitting cells based on a separator...